# Excel SQL query how to specify a column number not name

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I'm trying to query and filter an **OleDataTable** in C#, so not VBA inside of Excel.

```
string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [Columns1$] is not null";  // to filter out any empty values, works if used column name like [UserInfo].
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connExcel);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
OleDbCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
dtData = new DataTable();
DataSet dtDataT = new DataSet();
dtData.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string FilePath = copyfile.ToString();
da.Fill(dtData);
```

in the place of `[Columns1$]` I've tried `Columns(1)`, `Columns(A)`, not suceeded.

Comment: OleDb is not a database format. Are you working with Access or SQL Server?

Comment: @jscarle You can query Excel files with Microsoft.Jet.OleDb, but it's a very dated technology. The modern way would be to use a managed library dedicated to read Excel documents.

Comment: Oops, I misread that.

Comment: @silkfire what is the modern way now? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify HDR=NO in your connection string, after which columns names will be assigned automatically as F1, F2, etc.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/